The program doesn’t display the output
package q3;

public class Q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("please enter time in 24-hour format (hh:mm): ");
        String[] time = sc.nextLine().split(":");
        int hh,mm;
        hh = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
        mm = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);
        String p;
        if (hh >= 0 && hh <= 23 && mm >= 0 && mm <= 59) {
            p = hh >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
            hh = (hh == 0 || hh == 12) ? 12 : hh % 12;
            System.out.printf("%d:%02d %s%n", hh, mm, p);
        } else
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    }
}


Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out the [ask] and [tour] links to see how to ask questions, how to best use the site and what the site is for, and then consider [edit]ing and improving your question.  In particular, consider making your question more focused by adding text that tells us the details of what the code is supposed to do and what debugging you've done since doing this can help improve the question greatly, can improve its chances of getting a decent answer soon, and can reduce its chances of being closed, down-voted or deleted.

Also, does the code compile? And how do you try to run the code? Do you see any error messages? If so, please share them with us. Also, make sure that any code that you post is well-formatted and easy to read. I have formatted the above code for you to help you out.

Also, you aren't importing the Java Scanner with a import java.util.Scanner; statement above the class declaration that I can see. If true, then this code will fail compilation with a "cannot find symbol" error as per this Q&A: What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?. This is fixed, again, by adding the import statement.
